# Ruby change hash to single layer with square brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-hash

I've got a hash and I've found that with net/http posting I have to convert it into a flat format.

Example

```
invoice = { :no => "100", :date => "08/08/2022", :client => {:name => "Foo" } }
```

Would become

```
params = { "invoice[no]" => "100", "invoice[date]" => "08/08/2022", "invoice[client][name]" => "Foo" }
```

Is there a way to do this automatically? I've tried to_param & to_query, flatten and encode_www_form but they don't convert it to this required format.

The post action I'm doing is to a Ruby On Rails backend which I use Devise Tokens to authorise.

```
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, params)
```

Comment: you can also convert to a JSON object (string) and send it without flattening. Of course, you have to convert back to a hash on server.

Comment: I get the error "encode_www_form: undefined method map for" if I try passing the hash as json in the `Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, invoice.to_json)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`CGI.parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-parse) method. It parses an HTTP query string into a hash of key => value pairs

```
CGI.parse({ invoice: invoice }.to_query)

# => {"invoice[client][name]"=>["Foo"], "invoice[date]"=>["08/08/2022"], "invoice[no]"=>["100"]
```

Don't care about single-element arrays as values. It will works well

```
params = CGI.parse({ invoice: invoice }.to_query)
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, params)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this snippet should do the job:

```rb
invoice = { :no => "100", :date => "08/08/2022", :client => {:name => "Foo" } }

CGI.unescape({invoice:}.to_query)
   .split('&')
   .map{ |p| p.split('=') }
   .to_h

{"invoice[client][name]"=>"Foo", "invoice[date]"=>"08/08/2022", "invoice[no]"=>"100"}
```

First of all, we let ActiveRecord generate the query-like structure from a hash using the method `to_query`. We need to unescape the query string afterward since we don't want to have URL-encoded output there. After that we split the string by parameter using `split('&')` and every parameter into key-value using `split('=')`. Finally, we convert the output back into a hash.

Comment: Note: `{ invoice: }` works in new ruby versions, in older you need `{ invoice: invoice }` instead